# Neo4j Python Driver Syntax Error on MERGE statement

Tags: neo4j, python-3.8

I wrote a python script to interact with a neo4j db.

```
result_a = tx.run("MERGE (n:Word$tag_a { name: $name_a}) ON CREATE SET n.corpus = 1 ON MATCH SET n.corpus = n.corpus + 1 RETURN id(n) AS node_id", tag_a=tag_a, name_a=name_a)
```

where $tag_a contains a String staring with : and $name_a contains a String

when I execute my code I get this exception:

```
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input '{': expected ")" (line 1, column 21 (offset: 20))
"MERGE (n:Word$tag_a { name: $name_a}) ON CREATE SET n.corpus = 1 ON MATCH SET n.corpus = n.corpus + 1 RETURN id(n) AS node_id"
                     ^}
```

when I excecute a similar statement in neo4j console I get no error:

```
neo4j@neo4j> MERGE (n:Word:G { name: 'test'}) ON CREATE SET n.corpus = 1 ON MATCH SET n.corpus = n.corpus + 1 RETURN id(n) AS node_id
             ;
+---------+
| node_id |
+---------+
| 0       |
+---------+

1 row
ready to start consuming query after 843 ms, results consumed after another 528 ms
Added 1 nodes, Set 2 properties, Added 2 labels
```

It seems that it is not possible to use $tag_a the way I do. Is there a way to solve this without crafting the Query in an possible insecure way?

neo4j version neo4j 4.3.2

python version 3.8.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use f-string and then pass the parameter you need using python syntax.

```
query = f"MERGE (n:Word{tag_a} {{ name: {name_a}}}) ON CREATE SET n.corpus = 1 ON MATCH SET n.corpus = n.corpus + 1 RETURN id(n) AS node_id"
result_a = tx.run(query)
```

Just be cautious to always escape the query curly braces (duplicate them)

Comment: Thanks! I only had to add single quotes to {name_a} to make it work.  `query = f"MERGE (n:Word{tag_a} {{ name: '{name_a}'}}) ON CREATE SET n.corpus = 1 ON MATCH SET n.corpus = n.corpus + 1 RETURN id(n) AS node_id"
result_a = tx.run(query)`